# Kivy: how to update a bool outside class

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, checkbox, kivy

The bool is currently updated when I click on and off the checkbox however when I click the button it will always print the default value I define at the start. How can I update a bool that is outside the class, so that when I click the button and call the function, it updates the bool?

Also, how can I call a function like this when clicking the button, that is outside of the class?

Thanks

```
someBool = False


def someFunction():
    print(someBool)



class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #grid layout constructor
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #set columns for the layout
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="checkbox"))
        self.checkbox= CheckBox(active = False)
        self.add_widget(self.checkbox)

        #this will bind the label and checkbox
        self.checkbox.bind(active = self.checkboxActive)

        self.button= Button(text="Button")
        self.button.bind(on_press=someFunction)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

    def checkboxActive(self, checkbox, value):
        if value:
            someBool = True
        else:
            someBool = False


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change a value outside a function in python you have to specify its scope. It can be easily done with `global variable`.

Then for the button you have to pass an anonymous function to kivy `on_press` method linking it to the function you want. That way the press will trigger the function passed. So we will have to use `lambda` for this.

Try this code:

```py
someBool = False


def someFunction():
    global someBool

    print(someBool)


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # grid layout constructor
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # set columns for the layout
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="checkbox"))
        self.checkbox = CheckBox(active=False)
        self.add_widget(self.checkbox)

        # this will bind the label and checkbox
        self.checkbox.bind(active=self.checkboxActive)

        self.button = Button(text="Button")
        self.button.bind(on_press=lambda x: someFunction())
        self.add_widget(self.button)

    def checkboxActive(self, checkbox, value):
        global someBool

        if value:
            someBool = True
        else:
            someBool = False


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```